# get part of url wihout know full url

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

im using angular 4 and i use this code:

```
this.location.prepareExternalUrl(this.location.path()) === '/cursos/aula'
```

for remove navbar in 3 pages, but in one page i have params in url and this code not work. how i can capture url to remove navbar in url contains params?
ex:

```
this.location.prepareExternalUrl(this.location.path()) === '/cursos/aula?idCurso=3'
```

or

```
this.location.prepareExternalUrl(this.location.path()) === '/cursos/aula?idCurso=7'
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the Angular environment, but in vanila JS you can use window.location.href.

Comment: `if (yourUrl.includes('/cursos/aula?')) { ***do something*** }`, I have included `?`, because you want to check for params